# Only allow real visitors, and block custom "parsing" bots through PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a very large database of all items in a massive online game on my website, and so do my competitors. I however, am the only site to have pictures of all these items. All these pictures are on my server, eg. from 1.png to 99999.png (all in the same directory).

It's very easy for my competitors to create a simple file_get_contents/file_put_contents script to just parse all of this images to their own server and redistribute them their own way. Is there anything I can do about this?

Is there a way to limit (for example) everyone to only see/load 100 images per minute (I'm sure those scripts would rapidly parse all of the images)? Or even better, only allow real users to visit the URL's? I'm sure those scripts wont listen to a robots.txt file, so what would be a better solution? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Well, not using guessable filenames would probably be a good start.  Is that feasible, or are you stuck with them?  Also, what web server software are you using?  Most have (optional, third-party) rate limiting that might help here.

Comment: This question might be a lot easier to answer if you could tell us what a "real user" is...

Comment: You can try Fail2Ban, that might give you some reasonable throttling control.

Comment: If they are publicly available, they can be downloaded. It will just be a little bit harder / a few lines of code more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a watermark in your images that states that the images are copyrighted by you or your company.  Your competitors would have to remove the watermark and make the image look like there never was one, so that would definitely be a good measure to take.

If you're using Apache Web Server, create an image folder and upload an htaccess file that tells the server that only you and the server are allowed to see the files.  This will help hide the images from the parsing bots, as Apache would see that they are not authorized to see what's in the folder.  You'd need to have PHP load the images (not just pass img tags on) so that as far as the permissions system is concerned, the server is accessing the raw files.

On your PHP page itself, use a CAPTCHA device or some other robot detection method.

Comment: You should probably review [the post formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  In particular, note that indenting paragraphs does nothing here, and you have to have two newlines between them in order for them to actually be rendered as paragraphs instead of an unreadable dump'o'text.